# Why can't I extend C: partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

I want to extend my `C:` partition and I have freed 290 GB space.

[image]

But the `Extend Volume` option is still unavailable and grayed out, why can't I extend my `C:` partition?

Comment: Due to the layout of your disks, due to the existence of an extended partition, in other words the green box surrounding those 3 partitions. You would have to delete the other two partitions, then you would be able to extend your system partition, that's the simplest solution to this problem[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1081694/cant-extend-partition-to-use-free-space?rq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound is there any other way? because those 2 partitions are full and backing up that much of data is really hard.

Comment: @Moab not completely, because in this question extended partition only includes free space ,but in my case extended partition has about 560 GB data and free space and I'm looking for a way to not delete that much of data.

Comment: @hanie - The fact there are additional volumes in an extended partition does not change the fact, that is indeed the reason, you cannot extend your system disk.  How you do that would indeed be handled by the duplicated, ignoring the fact, it indicates you should get rid of a 450 MB partition.  However, I don't recommend any solution or performing any action, if your not willing to backup your data first.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating good backups before starting, since an error in partition editing
can greatly harm the disk integrity. The best would be to make an image backup
of the entire disk, if you can.

The problem:
You cannot extend `C:` over the free space, because it is not really free.
That space is included in the extended partition (the green rectangle),
so it is not considered as free outside of the extended partition.

In short, these are the operations that you need to do:

1. Move `J:` and `K:` left to the top of the extended partition so that the
   free space is at the end of the extended partition
2. Resize the extended partition to fit these two partitions,
   so the unallocated space is now outside of it and follows it
3. Move the extended partition right/bottom to the end of the disk,
   so the unallocated space now precedes the extended partition
   and immediately follows `C:`
4. Extend `C:` to include this unallocated space.

These operations cannot be done with the Disk Management utility of Windows,
so a third-party tool is required. Below are a couple of free tools that might
be able to do it. I don't know whether one or both can handle
extended partitions, so you will just need to try.

- [MiniTool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)
- [AOMEI Partition Assistant Freeware](https://www.diskpart.com/)